# When files are being moved are they stored in a memory?

Tags: shell, files, memory

When I move a file using the `mv` command, is this file first read, fully cached into a memory and then saved as another file? Or is it the same as writing

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line" >> output_file
done < input_file
```

Similarly with `cp`. When copying one file to another, is the file first fully cached into memory and then copied?

Comment: If you do an actual copy, the process will allocate a buffer in memory, read a chunk, then write a chunk. The whole file will pass through that buffer but is unlikely to all be in memory at the same time.

Comment: No matter what it won't be the same as using a shell loop to process text, which you should never do.  See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: My biggest concern about using `mv` is when I have a limited size of a memory. Is it (not) likely to run out of memory when using `mv` since it is managed "inside the command"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Often a `mv` is closer to a rename than a copy.  In a classic unix type file system, the inodes that contain the file data won't be replicated if the source and the destination are on the same mount point.  Instead a new filename is created that points to the same inodes, and the old filename is unlinked.

If the `mv` is to another mount point, then it will be an actual copy.  What fraction of it is in RAM at a time is an OS detail whose transparency to the user is not defined.

Just to give an example, if the data was considered actually copied to a new place, the file might be, to the user, conceptually 'written' to the disk.  But it could, at the OS level,  actually be residing in a buffer that hasn't been flushed to the hardware yet.

Comment: …and it does. Small files don't trigger a disk flush right away on most distrib default settings.